# Multiple histogram by category

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Im new to R and im tring to create an histogram.

my data looks like this:

```
                id age                               sub.types inter
1 TCGA-A8-A07O  60        Infiltrating duct carcinoma, NOS     6
2 TCGA-A7-A0CJ  65        Infiltrating duct carcinoma, NOS     6
3 TCGA-A7-A0CH  88        Infiltrating duct carcinoma, NOS     8
4 TCGA-A7-A0CG  86 Infiltrating duct and lobular carcinoma     8
5 TCGA-A7-A0CE  66        Infiltrating duct carcinoma, NOS     6
6 TCGA-A7-A0CD  75        Infiltrating duct carcinoma, NOS     7
```

i want to create an histogram so that for every groupe age (30-39, 40-49 etc)
i will get a bar devided and colored by sub types.

i maneged to create such a plot using ggplot for each groupe sepratly but not together (by using filter)

can any one derect me to the right answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cut` to group by range. Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389472/how-to-do-range-grouping-on-a-column-using-dplyr). Below is an example how to plot your data using `ggplot2` and `dplyr`. I've grouped by 10 years.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble::tribble(
                   ~id, ~age,                                ~sub.types, ~inter,
        "TCGA-A8-A07O",  60L,        "Infiltrating duct carcinoma, NOS",     6L,
        "TCGA-A7-A0CJ",  65L,        "Infiltrating duct carcinoma, NOS",     6L,
        "TCGA-A7-A0CH",  88L,        "Infiltrating duct carcinoma, NOS",     8L,
        "TCGA-A7-A0CG",  86L, "Infiltrating duct and lobular carcinoma",     8L,
        "TCGA-A7-A0CE",  66L,        "Infiltrating duct carcinoma, NOS",     6L,
        "TCGA-A7-A0CD",  75L,        "Infiltrating duct carcinoma, NOS",     7L
        )

df %>% 
  group_by(age.group = cut(age, breaks= seq(0, 100, by = 10))) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(age.group, fill = sub.types)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Tnx! but i need the bars to be side by side and not on each other, any ideas?

Comment: @noam just add `position = "dodge"` to `geom_bar()`. Take a look in the reference: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html