# Group by range and calculate mean in R and graph

Tags: r

I have a table input of data on cars. Roughly 73 observations with 11 variables. I was tasked to find the mean of MPG by gear_ratio. This is the output I receive after completing an aggregate function.

```
dfdata=data.frame(cars10)
aggregate(x= dfdata$mpg, by=list(dfdata$gear_ratio), FUN=mean)
```

| Gear_ratio | Mean_MPG |
| --- | --- |
| 2.19 | 14 |
| 2.24 | 21 |
| 2.2.26 | 25 |
| 2.28 | 17 |
| 2.2.47 | 21 |
| 2.53 | 17 |
| 2.56 | 17.5 |
| 2.73 | 21.3 |
| 2.75 | 20.12 |
| 2.87 | 34 |
| 3.05 | 23.6 |
| 3.15 | 17 |
| 3.5 | 23 |
| 3.87 | 18 |
| 3.9 | 30.3 |

Next I would like to group and graph the following means by a range of Gear_ratio. The ranges need to be a) 2.0-2.5 b) 2.5 to 3.0 c)3.0-3.5 and d)3.5-4.0. I'd like to change colors for each group as well.

*Wasn't sure if there was a way to group by range in the initial aggregate function I created to find the mean in the first place.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389472/how-to-do-range-grouping-on-a-column-using-dplyr

Comment: Please provide example data in a fomrat that can be readily copied, pasted and worked with. The posted ```Gear_ratio``` doesn't appear to be numeric.

Comment: What sort of graph do you want to produce? And could you clarify what you want plotted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I think the OP is asking for. I'm using `mtcars` data for demonstration and using the `wt` variable instead of gears as it has values similar to your `gear_ratio`:

```
library(dplyr) # for select and case_when and group_by
data = mtcars%>%
  select(wt, mpg)%>%
  mutate(wt_group =  case_when(wt >4 ~ ">4",  # form the groups based on ranges
                              wt >=3.5 ~ "3.5-4", # case_when will read this in order, so no need to do conditional statements such as wt >=3.0 but <3.5
                              wt >=3.0 ~ "3.0-3.5",
                              wt >=2.5 ~ "2.5-3.0",
                              wt >=2.0 ~ "2.0-2.5",
                              wt < 2.0 ~ "<2.0"))%>%
  group_by(wt_group)%>%
  summarise(mean_mpg = mean(mpg) )
> head(data)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  wt_group mean_mpg
  <chr>       <dbl>
1 <2.0         30.5
2 >4           13.0
3 2.0-2.5      25.7
4 2.5-3.0      20.8
5 3.0-3.5      19.3
6 3.5-4        15.7
```

Then for the plot :

```
library(ggplot2)
plot = ggplot(data, aes(x= wt_group, y = mean_mpg , fill = wt_group))+
  geom_col()
plot
```

[image]

Please edit the question and I can update answer if this doesn't give you what you need.

Comment: thank you so much! This worked just as I wanted. I had to modify since my dataset did not contain a gear_ratio < 2 or >4 . Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(gear_group = cut(Gear_ratio,seq(0,4,.5)))

# A tibble: 15 x 3
   Gear_ratio Mean_MPG gear_group
        <dbl>    <dbl> <fct>     
 1       2.19     14   (2,2.5]   
 2       2.24     21   (2,2.5]   
 3       2.26     25   (2,2.5]   
 4       2.28     17   (2,2.5]   
 5       2.47     21   (2,2.5]   
 6       2.53     17   (2.5,3]   
 7       2.56     17.5 (2.5,3]   
 8       2.73     21.3 (2.5,3]   
 9       2.75     20.1 (2.5,3]   
10       2.87     34   (2.5,3]   
11       3.05     23.6 (3,3.5]   
12       3.15     17   (3,3.5]   
13       3.5      23   (3,3.5]   
14       3.87     18   (3.5,4]   
15       3.9      30.3 (3.5,4]
```