# Merge rows in increments

Tags: r, function, data-cleaning

I have a data set that had fico scores. I want to merge them so it is in increments of five, I.e the fico column will be 650, 655, 670, etc. Is there an r function or multiple r functions to acheive this? If I was to use the cut function how would I go about that?
[Here is part of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKT0n.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's hard to understand what exactly you want without seeing your data. Please [edit] your post to include at least a sample of your data, which you can get using `dput(dataname)` or `dput(head(dataname))`. Please also share a [mre] showing anything you've tried so far, or an example of what you want your output to look like.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `cut` function in base R, coupled with the `mutate` and`group_by` functions from the `tidyverse` would be helpful here.

For example, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49814705/13254537 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/32389527/13254537